# SQL: Join Statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to produce an output where only the person with Surname = "Berry" lessons are shown, with Date in Ascending order.

```
SELECT c.booking_number AS "Reference",
       c.ldate          AS "Lesson Date",
       s.first_name     AS "Instructor First Name",
       s.surname        AS "Instructor Last Name"
FROM   am_lessons c
       join am_staff s
         ON ( c.staff_id = c.staff_id )
       join am_bookings m
         ON ( c.booking_number = m.booking_number )
       join am_customers f
         ON ( f.customer_id = c.customer_id )
WHERE  f.surname = 'Berry'
ORDER  BY c.ldate ASC
```

The Statement runs but produces repetitions of "Booking Numbers" and "First Name" and "Second Name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have some extra/incorrect joins:

```
SELECT c.booking_number AS "Reference",
       c.ldate          AS "Lesson Date",
       s.first_name     AS "Instructor First Name",
       s.surname        AS "Instructor Last Name"
FROM   am_lessons c
       join am_staff s
         ON ( c.staff_id = s.staff_id ) -- should be s.Staff_Id
       -- JOIN AM_Bookings m           -- this join is not needed
       -- ON (c.Booking_Number = m.Booking_Number)
       join am_customers f
         ON ( f.customer_id = c.customer_id )
WHERE  f.surname = 'Berry'
ORDER  BY c.ldate ASC
```

Secondly, you may have duplicate rows in your tables.  If this is the case, either fix the data, or add a DISTINCT modifier.

Note: It is possible that the join on AM_Bookings was being used to filter out records that have no associated Booking_Number. If this is the case, you can simply filter on `c.Booking_Number IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: That was the answer, I had the right idea, but added a few things and over complicated it. Thanks PinnyM!

Comment: @PinnyM How do you know that the second join is not needed? As fas I know if you have a matching you need to join it.Please explain

Comment: @AsfakulIslam Since the `am_lessons` table joins with `am_bookings` on `booking_number`, it seemed fair to assume that `am_lessons.booking_number` was a foreign key.  In this case, the join wouldn't accomplish anything except to filter out records where  a join could not be made, since no fields from the `am_bookings` table are actually used in the query.  A more efficient way to perform the same filter would be to simply check that the `am_lessons.booking_number` is not NULL.